# How can I store colors to be reused later for pgf-pie charts?

Tags: pgfkeys, pgf-pie

I am trying to store a set of colors in the corresponding  pgf key and then recall it later. However attempting to do this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
    
\pgfkeys{/colorsetA/.style={color={red,green,blue,orange}}}
\pgfkeys{/colorsetB/.style={color={orange,blue,magenta,yellow}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[colorsetA]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\pie[pos={8,0}, colorsetB] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/colorsetA' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \pie[colorsetA]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}`

What am I doing wrong, is it the wrong key I try to access, or am I recalling it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your `colorsetA` and `colorsetB` in the right scope. `pgf-pie` looks for keys relative to `/pgfpie/`, so you need

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

% CHANGED: Added /pgfpie
\pgfkeys{/pgfpie/colorsetA/.style={color={red,green,blue,orange}}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfpie/colorsetB/.style={color={orange,blue,magenta,yellow}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[colorsetA]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\pie[pos={8,0}, colorsetB] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel and indeed, something was changed in ```pgf-pie``` over time, as I think those keys used to be global in the past. However how could I have found that out by myself? Would I need to look into Line 231 https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/blob/master/tex/latex/pgf-pie/tikzlibrarypie.code.tex#L231 or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

A 'root' key also works but then you need to include `/` in the `\pie` argument. If you want you can also use `\tikzset`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
    
\pgfkeys{/colorsetA/.style={color={red,green,blue,orange}}}
\tikzset{/colorsetB/.style={color={orange,blue,magenta,yellow}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[/colorsetA]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\pie[pos={8,0}, /colorsetB] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative, I upvoted it, but think the other solution is more straightforward.